Java files are displayed as orange icons by IntelliJ and can't be opened
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Community Edition).
All my Java files are showing as Orange Icons (with a coffee cup) in the project file browser on the left hand side. I click on the file name and nothing happens.  If I then right click on the file and click on "Reload from Disk", then the filename turns white, and I can then click on the file and it opens for editing in the main window.
However, if I shut down the IDE or click on the menu item: "File -> Reload all from disk", then the files turn orange again and can't be opened.  I have tried invalidating the cache and restarting - but it does not work.
I have noticed on startup that the files are fleetingly white for a while before they turn orange.


The IDE doesn't recognize your project as a Java module and just shows you the files are simple text files. You need to review your IDE setup, I assume it's a Maven project so you can check this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html

The reason is that IntelliJ IDE has not recognized your project as a Maven project yet.
Solution: Right click to pom.xml > Add as Maven Project


Thank you for your answer.  I right clicked on the pom file as suggested.  It was added as a Maven project.  so I unlinked it as a Maven project and then re-added it as a Maven Project.  Still broken.  I therefore built a new maven project again using an Archetype. (simple).  I then updated my POM dependencies and then copied in my Java files.  It is now working.  This is about the 4th time I have had to recover my Project in this way - after it got corrupted.  Probably user error; I am new to IntelliJ - but I am finding it quite problematic.

For me  this error occured after adding something to the classpath. It was a recommended action of Intellij but after adding it, these orange cups appeared. What worked for me was to simply revert the changes (ctrl + z) until Intellij asked "Do you want to remove x from your classpath?" and afterwards the orange cups disappeared and I was able to run it again.
There's probably a better solution, maybe it is possible to remove it from the classpath manually.
Hope this helps.
